# Convert Java to Jython

Tags: java, python, jython, ignition

I would like to know if it's possible to convert the code below from Java to Jython.
I want to create a JTree Table in Ignition in order to visualize the data by clicking a row and the user can see a subview row that contains some information of the selected row.
I tried to look for some online language conversion site but unfortunately I found nothing; I have also tried to ask on other forums but I have not received answers that can resolve my doubt ...
I hope this is the right place to ask these kinds of questions.
Thank you all!
Java code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.tree.*;

public class TreeWithTableRenderer extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JTree tree;

    public TreeWithTableRenderer() {
        DefaultMutableTreeNode AA1 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("AA1");
        DefaultMutableTreeNode AA2 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("AA2");
        DefaultMutableTreeNode A = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("A");
        A.add(AA1);
        A.add(AA2);
        DefaultMutableTreeNode BB1 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("BB1");
        DefaultMutableTreeNode BB2 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("BB2");
        DefaultMutableTreeNode B = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("B");
        B.add(BB1);
        B.add(BB2);
        DefaultMutableTreeNode CC1 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("CC1");
        DefaultMutableTreeNode CC2 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("CC2");
        DefaultMutableTreeNode C = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("C");
        C.add(CC1);
        C.add(CC2);
        DefaultMutableTreeNode root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("root");
        root.add(A);
        root.add(B);
        root.add(C);
        tree = new JTree(root);
        tree.setCellRenderer(new MyTableInTreeCellRenderer());
        tree.setRowHeight(0);
        JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane(tree);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        add(jsp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    class MyTableInTreeCellRenderer extends JPanel implements TreeCellRenderer {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private JTable table;

        public MyTableInTreeCellRenderer() {
            super(new BorderLayout());
            table = new JTable();
            JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
            add(scrollPane);
        }

        public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent(JTree tree, Object value,
                boolean selected, boolean expanded, boolean leaf, int row, boolean hasFocus) {
            final String v = (String) ((DefaultMutableTreeNode) value).getUserObject();
            table.setModel(new DefaultTableModel() {

                private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                @Override
                public int getRowCount() {
                    return 2;
                }

                @Override
                public int getColumnCount() {
                    return 2;
                }

                @Override
                public Object getValueAt(int row, int column) {
                    return v + ":" + row + ":" + column;
                }
            });
            table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());
            return this;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                new TreeWithTableRenderer().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: What happened when you tried to convert it?

Comment: I don't know exactly how to convert ... I don't know Java so well!

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this yourself?

Comment: Probably yes, I will try!